# Different between FormGroup and [FormGroup] with brackets

Tags: angular, forms, dynamic

Im building a Dyanmic Form in angular, and im still struggling to understand the different between using
FormGroup and [FormGroup] (With brackets)
and FormControlName vs [FormControlName]

Comment: Some code as context might help.

Answer (score 2):

This is fundamental concept of Angular to bind property in template (check [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-expressions)). 
With brackets you bind variable, which is declared in your component. Without brackets you bind value of variable.

Difference between `formControlName` vs `[formControlName]` is what in first one, `formControlName` was declared in `FormGroup` in component, in second one is what is was declared as independent `FormControl` in component.

Example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile-editor',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="profileForm">
    <label>
        First Name:
        <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
    </label>
    </form>
 `
})
export class ProfileEditorComponent {
  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl('')
  });
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile-editor',
  template: `
    <form>
        <label>
            First Name:
            <input type="text" [formControlName]="firstName">
        </label>
    </form>
 `
})
export class ProfileEditorComponent {
  firstName = new FormControl('');
}
```

Check Angular [documentation about reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).